# Why is my hover() not working as intended? It appends and removes the div many time as I scroll over the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

So the idea is this: when I hover on any of the images, jQuery should append a div with class `.blackDiv` which is positioned `absolute` over the image and turn it black and then as soon as I hover off, the div should be removed in order for the image to be visible again. However as of now, as I move the mouse over the image, the div is getting appended and removed many many times creating a blinking effect. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
echo    "<div class='imageContainer'>" 
                ."<h1>".$row["name"].'</h1>' 
                .'<div class="stickyImageContainer"><a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="uploadedImg" src="/uploads/'.$row["path"] .'" alt="Random image" /></a> ';

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        if ($hasVoted < 1) {
            echo    "<div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'>
                    <form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='voteType' value='voteImage'>
                        <button class='upvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'><img class='arrowUp' src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'></button>
                    </form>";

            echo "<div class='ratingNumber'>";
                if ($row['upvotes'] - $row['downvotes'] <= 0) {
                    echo "<p>0</p>";
                } else {
                    echo $row['upvotes'] - $row['downvotes'];
                }

            echo "</div>";

            echo    "<form class='downvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='downvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='voteType' value='voteImage'>
                        <button class='downvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='downvoteImage'><img class='arrowDown' src='../images/Social Media/arrowDown.png' alt='submit'></button>
                    </form></div>";
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.uploadedImg').hover(function(){
        var image = $(this);
        var imageParent = image.closest('.stickyImageContainer');
        imageParent.append('<div class="blackDiv">bye world</div>');
    }, function() {
        var image = $(this);
        var imageParent = image.closest('.stickyImageContainer');
        imageParent.find('.blackDiv').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Provide your HTML as well

Comment: Done, totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When then `div` gets appended on top of the image, it goes **between the image and the cursor**, causing the cursor to **hover off** the image, which causes the other function to run which removes the `div`, which causes the cursor to **hover on** the image which causes the first function to insert the `div` and you see the loop...which causes the blinking effect.

To solve this attach the `mouseenter` event on `.uploadedImg` and the `mouseleave` event on the inserted `div` itself.

Like this,

```
$('.imageContainer').on('mouseenter', '.uploadedImg', function(){
  var image = $(this);
  var imageParent = image.closest('.stickyImageContainer');
  imageParent.append('<div class="blackDiv">bye world</div>');
}).on('mouseleave', '.blackDiv', function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: I assumed it was something like this but couldn't figure it out myself. Thanks.